# My authentication form does not load the CSS

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc

I have an authentication form which use AD to validate users. But when I run the project, the login page appears it has not the CSS load, after the user validation everything work, such as the CSS.

This app is for **IIS 7 Webserver**. I've already tried to add the tag  but it isn't working, also tried to place the various tag with different order but without success

My web.config code:

```
<location path="~/myCSSFolder">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://myserver.mydomain.COM:389/DC=mydomain,DC=COM" />
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1"></compilation>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name=".ADAuthCookie" loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="45" slidingExpiration="false" />
  </authentication>
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
<system.web>
  <membership defaultProvider="ADMembershipProvider">
    <providers>
      <clear />
      <add
        name="ADMembershipProvider"
        type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider"
        connectionStringName="ADConnectionString"
        attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName"
      />
   </providers>
  </membership>
</system.web>
```

I expect a page with 2 `textbox`, 1 `button` and a `navbar` with all the links that i need, all of this appears but without any style, so no background image, no fonts, no colours

Comment: are your css files located in myCSSFolder or sub directories in it?

Comment: @BrettCaswell my css is in myCSSFolder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your web.config, you are denying anonymous users access to your `myCssFolder` and all sub directories and resources. `<deny users="?" />`

```
<location path="~/myCSSFolder">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

remove `<deny users="?" />` for this `location` and it will allow all users to access your css files.